# Is there a "universal connection" on the universal $G$-bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, connections, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ a Lie group, $X$ a smooth manifold. Let $EG \rightarrow BG$ be the (topological) universal $G$-bundle.

We know for every (topological) principal $G$-bundle $P \rightarrow X$
there is a (continuous) classifying map $f_P : X \rightarrow BG$
such that $P \approx f_P^*EG$.

I was wondering if there exists a (perhaps infinite-dimensional) smooth structure on $EG \rightarrow BG$,
and a principal $G$-connection $\omega$ on $EG$,
such that every smooth principal $G$-bundle on $X$ equipped with connection
is a pullback of $EG \rightarrow BG$ equipped with $\omega$, along some smooth map $X\rightarrow BG$?

Comment: This paper by Narasimhan and Ramanan may be of interest: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372896

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you had in mind, but another more modern reference for the universal connection on the universal principal $G$-bundle with connection in the language of abstract homotopy theory can be found [here](https://math.mit.edu/juvitop/pastseminars/notes_2019_Fall/Freed-Hopkins.pdf). In this paper the *diffeological spaces* or *differentiable spaces* of Mostow are replaced with simplicial (pre)sheaves (if I understand correctly).

In this context, the universal principal $G$-bundle with connection is a map of simplicial sheaves $E_{\nabla}G\to B_{\nabla}G$ where $E_{\nabla}G(M)$ is the nerve of the groupoid of *trivial* $G$-bundles with connection over $M$ and $B_{\nabla}G$(M) is the nerve of the groupoid of *all* principal $G$-bundles with connection over $M$. The map itself is the canonical map associated with the homotopy quotient $E_{\nabla}G//G$ (here $G$ is the discrete simplicial sheaf represented by G) composed with an equivalence $E_{\nabla}G//G\xrightarrow{\sim}B_{\nabla}G$. In this sense it truly does exhibit the structure of a principal $G$-bundle as the quotient of a "space" (simplicial sheaf) by the free action of a "Lie group" (simplicial sheaf represented by a Lie group). The universal connection is a map of simplicial sheaves $\Theta^{\mathrm{univ}}:E_{\nabla}G\to \Omega^{1}\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ where $\Omega^{1}\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ is the discrete simplicial sheaf that assigns to a manifold $M$ the set $\Omega^{1}(M:\mathfrak{g})$. Concretely, $\Theta^{\mathrm{univ}}$ maps a trivial bundle $P\to M$ with connection $\omega\in\Omega^{1}(P;\mathfrak{g})$ to the pullback $s^{*}\omega$ by a global section $M\xrightarrow{s}P$.

It is proven in the paper that given any *honest* principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ with *honest* connection $\omega\in\Omega^{1}(P;\mathfrak{g})$, there exists a unique map of simplicial sheaves $P\xrightarrow{f} E_{\nabla}G$ such that $\omega = f^{*}\Theta^{\mathrm{univ}}$. It is implicit that one must first upgrade $P$ and $X$ to (discrete representable) simplicial sheaves, and further upgrade $\omega$ to a map of simplicial sheaves $P\xrightarrow{\omega}\Omega^{1}\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ in order for any of this to make sense, but a similar "upgrading" is done in the framework using diffeological spaces.

The advantage of this language is that, at the expense of introducing a complicated framework, the proof of existence, i.e. the construction of the map $f$ and the proof of its desired properties, becomes an almost tautological affair of tracing the relevant definitions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's an nLab article on the [universal connection](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+connection); it mentions references describing both the case for bounded dimension (including the paper linked in the comments above), and a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-14/issue-2/The-differentiable-space-structures-of-Milnor-classifying-spaces-simplicial-complexes/10.4310/jdg/1214434974.full) describing the unbounded dimension case using differentiable spaces.